# Riemann Lebesgue Lemma for polynomial?

Tags: complex-integration

I was asked to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \exp(i\cdot n\cdot p(x))\;dx =0 $$

for nonconstant real polynomial $p(x)$.

if $p(x)$ is of degree $1$... It reduces to Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

I think similar motivation will work... but not able to

Comment: You may want to proofread your question whether the limit symbol is omitted or not.

Comment: Did you meant to have a limit in there?

Comment: oh.. I made a huge mistake.

Comment: we need a limit n goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose first that $p'$ is nonzero on $(0,1)$, so that $p$ has an inverse $q$ on $[0,1]$ which is differentiable everywhere except possibly at the endpoints. Then making the substitution $u=p(x)$ yields
$$\int_0^1 e^{i \, n \, p(x)} \, dx=\int_{p(0)}^{p(1)} e^{i \, n \, u} \, \frac{1}{p'(q(u))}\, du \, .$$
The function $f(u)=\dfrac{1}{p'(q(u))}$ is continuous on the interior of the interval of integration. At $p(0)$ and $p(1)$, $f(u)$ is either continuous or grows like $u^{-(n-1)/n}$ for some $n>1$. So $f(u)$ is $L^1$, which means the ordinary Riemann-Lebesgue lemma applies.

In general, $p'$ may not be nonzero on the entire interval. But since $p$ is a polynomial, we can split $[0,1]$ up into some finite collection of intervals over which $p'$ is nonzero, and make the above substitution separately on each of them...

Comment: I never thought change of variable will work.. Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't you have the derivative dividing after the change of variable? $du = p'(x) dx$, then $du = \frac{1}{p'( p^{-1} (u) )} du.$

Comment: The good thing is that the function $\frac{1}{p'(p^{-1}(u))}$ is indeed $L^1$.

Comment: @Gonzalo Benavides: Yes, 10-years-ago-me should have known better than that!